# jQuery append not working and tells me createDocumentFragment is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying a very simple jQuery command to append my name to the browser:

```
$(document).append('<h1>Name</h1>');
```

But it fails with this message:

> jquery-3.4.1.js:4789 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'createDocumentFragment' of null
> at buildFragment (jquery-3.4.1.js:4789)
> at domManip (jquery-3.4.1.js:5890)
> at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery-3.4.1.js:6081)
> at :1:13

What should I do?

Comment: you cannot append anything to `document`. Try `$('body')`.

Answer (score 0):

This small example works.
An example with JQuery and JavaScript.

```js
 var h = document.createElement("H1");
 var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
 h.appendChild(t);
 document.body.appendChild(h);


 var h = document.createElement("H1");
 var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
 h.appendChild(t);
 document.getElementById("app").appendChild(h)

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').append('<h1>Name</h1>');
  $('#name').append('<h1>Name</h1>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You should explain why this is working and ```$(document)``` not...

Comment: The author already knew the API. It is just the element used as the anchor for the commands that is wrong. Do elaborate.

Comment: A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Comment: You need a selector like a class or id to append your h1 Tag. You can also use 'body' to append the h1 Tag. See my example above.